# How to send GraphQLrequest using Cypress

Tags: testing, cypress

I wonder if there is a way to send GraphQL mutations using Cypress?
There is `cy.intercept()` but this is more for waiting for responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cy.request()`, you only need to know how GraphQL works and what format of the payload you need to send to your endpoint.

An example could be:

```js
describe('GraphQl example', () => {
  it('Send req to graphql endpoint', () => {
    const query = `{ 
      speakers(name: "Miloš") {
        id
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }`;
    cy
      .request({
        url: 'https://demagog.cz/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        body: { query }
      })
      .then(res => {
        cy
          .log(res);
      });
  });
});
```

And I easily get a successful response with data:

[image]

Things you need to know:

- how to use GraphQL endpoints, how to form queries
- how to use `cy.request()`
- and of course some Cypress basics